# Compile folder with .java files and Jar it

Tags: java, windows, compilation

I'm trying to figure out compiling a folder with Java source files in it. 
There's a folder structure (root folders are org.AppName.i18n and META-INF). Eventually I need to get a Jar with the same structure and .java's converted to .class'es. Any hints how to make it? I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ant for this: http://ant.apache.org/

Comment: I have Ant, but it asks for a build file.

Comment: You have to write one, but this is really easy! Have a look at the manual.

Answer (score 1):

A build tool, like [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) is perfect for this.

See the [tutorial for java projects](http://gradle.org/tutorial_java_projects.html).

Create a build.gradle file, where you use the [java plugin](http://gradle.org/java_plugin.html):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

You either need to move your java files to src/main/java, or specify the source folder in build.gradle, something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Then run 'gradle jar'